# Is it possible to use Hazelcast with Netflix OSS stack?

Tags: hazelcast, spring-cloud, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Currently we are building a platform using Netflix OSS stack (Microservices). We want to use HazelCast as a caching solution. Can anyone please help me like, how can I integrate HazelCast into Netflix OSS. is it recommended ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what parts of the stack you want to integrate Hazelcast. We have a Eureka discovery plugin which makes it possible to discover other Hazelcast nodes. You can put Hystrix in front of Hazelcast calls but remember those are fault tolerant, so they might are re-run. I never tried Governator or Zuul but I think there was a user to successfully integrate the latter one with Hazelcast.

Comment: Hi @noctarious .. I want to use it as a caching solution, Can I do that ?

Comment: Still depends on where to put it in the stack, I would guess yes but you'll most probably just have to try.

Comment: For the most part I'd say it's orthogonal. You can certainly use Hazelcast in your app for caching just like you could use any database. Netflix open source doesn't care.